# Spring boot with Stomp gives HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I have been using spring boot with stomp server for websocket with sockjs as frontend library. Intermittently I get the following message in the logs.

```
11:10:15.017 [37] [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8']
```

As far as I have read this occurs when wrong content type is recieved in controller. But this data comes in through websocket and all the data is made to string using `JSON.Stringify` from frontend and recieved by `@MessageMapping` annoted controller. Iam not able to understand why this error occurs , could there be other reasons for this issue to occur. I have used ActiveMQ as the message broker.

Can someone throw some light into what could be happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue myself. Issue occurs when the stomp server try to send heart beat from server to client. If the client disconnects while the server is sending the heartbeat, the issue occurs.

Comment: What did you do about it?

Comment: @StefanNorberg Commented out the code where the disconnect message is send from the sockjs or stompjs library. Dont remember which library

Comment: This causing the message queue to break totally. No traffic after this error. How can I recover me without the need to restart the app?