# springboot stomp send heart beat to closed session lead to error “No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] ...”

Tags: websocket, stomp, sockjs, heartbeat

I'm using spring boot stomp with built-in message broker. i got two error message in my error log:
"No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8'" and "No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8'". i got two answer from google, it seems that   when server send heart beat to a closed session, the error occur. The same issue [Spring boot makes warning log HttpMessageNotWritableException from the reason that might come from WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74119176/spring-boot-makes-warning-log-httpmessagenotwritableexception-from-the-reason-th?noredirect=1)  and [Spring boot with Stomp gives HttpMessageNotWritableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112761/spring-boot-with-stomp-gives-httpmessagenotwritableexception)  they figured the issue, but no solution. what can i do.appreciate for any help

hope no such error log in my application